# asp.net core 3.1 - Worker Service Template - SignalR Implementation

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, backgroundworker, asp.net-core-3.1, background-service

I am trying to broadcast a message to clients with a worker service in .net core 3.1. I don't have any Startup.cs (no endpoint etc.). I only have a Program.cs:

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseWindowsService()
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                //services.AddSignalR();
                services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
            });
}
```

And this is the worker (Worker.cs):

```cs
public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;
    //private readonly IHubContext<OperatorHub, IMessage> _operatorHub;



    public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger/*, IHubContext<OperatorHub, IMessage> operatorHub*/)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        //_operatorHub = operatorHub;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            //await _operatorHub.Clients.All.SendMessage("hello fucking world!");
            _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
            await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
        }
    }
}
```

From what I gathered from seperate documentation (but right there is no documentation on internet about this)
This is an Interface I created (IMessage.cs):

```cs
public interface IMessage
{
    Task SendMessage(string message);
}
```

And this is a hub class (OperatorHub.cs):

```cs
public class OperatorHub : Hub<IMessage>
{
    public async Task BroadcastMessage(string message)
    {
        await Clients.All.SendMessage(message);
    }
}
```

When I run I get an exception because of the line `services.AddSignalR();` in Program.cs.
I tried to add something like `services.AddSingleton<OperatorHub>()` under ConfigureServices but no luck either.

A little help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you have on your `Configure` method?

Comment: There is no configure method came with the default template, and that's all of the code. I have seen your answer to that other similar question and I have tried to implement what you have proposed but It does not work for this template.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the base template does not include the library/package that you want to use for signalr, nuget (.net pacakage manager) will have to but used to add it. Try adding the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR` nuget package or edit your .csproj file to add the package manually to look similar to this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Worker">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="3.1.4"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR" Version="1.1.0"/>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: I already did that. With nuget package, it does not work.

Comment: Are you hosting this on GitHub or is there a place to see more code. I was able to make a worker .net core app with it